# PHP transclusion question (regex)

Tags: php, regex

I am busy with an application that uses transclusion. Basically I need to parse a given text and capture tags as follows:

```
  {{author: name |
    book : sometitle |
    year : someyear |
    img  : {{img:.....}}
  }}
```

My problem is that I need to recursively parse what is within the double curly brackets and replace it with other text. 
Is it possible to have recursion just using regex alone, can anyone offer a solution?

If you familiar with wiki text what I am doing is very similar.

Comment: As you've discovered, you cannot do this using a regex.  You'll need a full-blown parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done simply with regex and iteration, though MediaWiki doesn't use regex (except for parsing parameters).  See the `braceSubstitution` function in includes/parser/Parser.php